# Set content based on element type with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying create a function that can set content (value or text) of an HTML element without worrying about the type of the element. So far I have made up to to this:

```
function setContent(elm, value){
    if(elm.is('[value]')){                           
        elm.val(value);
    }else{                                      
        elm.text(value);
    }
}
```

but the problem here is it is not working for `select` element. The working snippet is added below, can you please give a lead?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
    $('#setContent').on('click', function(){           
          $('#setElements').children().each(function( index ) {    
              var newContent = $('#newContent').val();
              setContent($(this), newContent );
          });     
    });                                   
            
});   

function setContent(elm, value){
    if(elm.is('[value]')){                           
        elm.val(value);
    }else{                                      
        elm.text(value);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Content: <input type="text" id="newContent" value="Two" />
<button id="setContent">Set Content</button>
<hr />
Elemets to set contents:  
<div id="setElements">
  <input type="text" value="This is a Text" />
  <input type="hidden" value="This is a Hidden" />
  <input type="button" value="This is a Button" />
  <button>This is a Button2</button>
  <div>This is a DIV</div>
  <span>SPAN here</span>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  
  <br>
  Not working on: <select>
        <option value="One">One</option>
        <option value="Two">Two</option>
        <option value="Three">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Are the only expected values for `<select>` element the `value` of the existing `<option>` child elements?

Comment: Yeah, that will be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass selector `"[value], :has([value])"` to `.is()` at `if` condition

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#setContent').on('click', function() {
    $('#setElements').children().each(function(index) {
      var newContent = $('#newContent').val();
      setContent($(this), newContent);
    });
  });

});

function setContent(elm, value) {
  if (elm.is("[value], :has([value])"))
  {
    elm.val(value);
  } else {
    elm.text(value);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Content:
<input type="text" id="newContent" value="Two" />
<button id="setContent">Set Content</button>
<hr />Elemets to set contents:
<div id="setElements">
  <input type="text" value="This is a Text" />
  <input type="hidden" value="This is a Hidden" />
  <input type="button" value="This is a Button" />
  <button>This is a Button2</button>
  <div>This is a DIV</div>
  <span>SPAN here</span>
  <p>Paragraph</p>

  <br>Not working on:
  <select>
    <option value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two">Two</option>
    <option value="Three">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, this is pretty great! works like charm. Thanks a lot for the solution.

Comment: I found a case, if a `<div>` has an input as child element, this will not assign text to that div. It is good in some cases but not good in another case.

Comment: @DipuRaj Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: @DipuRaj You can use `.add()` at `if` statement `elm.add($("[value]", elm)).val(value);` https://jsfiddle.net/19xpLu4d/3/

Answer (score 3):

`<select>` requires appending a new `option`. Modify `setContent()` like this

```
function setContent(elm, value){
        if(elm.is('select') ){
            // empty element, and then append new option
            elm.empty().append( $('<option/>', { value: value, html:value }) );
        } else if(elm.is('[value]')){                           
            elm.val(value);
        }else{                                      
            elm.text(value);
        }
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
    $('#setContent').on('click', function(){           
          $('#setElements').children().each(function( index ) {    
              var newContent = $('#newContent').val();
              setContent($(this), newContent );
          });     
    });                                   
            
});   

function setContent(elm, value){
    if(elm.is('select') ){
        elm.empty().append( $('<option/>', { value: value, html:value }) );
    } else if(elm.is('[value]')){                           
        elm.val(value);
    }else{                                      
        elm.text(value);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Content: <input type="text" id="newContent" value="Two" />
<button id="setContent">Set Content</button>
<hr />
Elemets to set contents:  
<div id="setElements">
  <input type="text" value="This is a Text" />
  <input type="hidden" value="This is a Hidden" />
  <input type="button" value="This is a Button" />
  <button>This is a Button2</button>
  <div>This is a DIV</div>
  <span>SPAN here</span>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  
  <br>
  Not working on: <select>
        <option value="One">One</option>
        <option value="Two">Two</option>
        <option value="Three">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but here the select already has the options 'Two' but that is not getting selected and it is clearing the other options too :(

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following script

```
function setContent(elm, value) {
    if (elm.is('select')){
        elm.val(value);
    } else {
        if(elm.is('[value]')){                           
            elm.val(value);
        }else{                                    
            elm.text(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would also written as combined `elm.is('[value], select')`

Answer (score 0):

change your setContent function as follows and try

```
function setContent(elm, value) {   
  var tag = elm[0].tagName;   
  if(['DIV','SPAN','BUTTON','P'].indexOf(tag) >= 0)
    elm.text(value);   
  else if(['INPUT','SELECT'].indexOf(tag) >= 0)
    elm.val(value);    
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I really don't want to end up adding all the tag names in the code.